# In Objective-c, detecting when all of a variable number of UIButton have been pressed

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, nsmutablearray

I have a quick question about the best method to check if all of my `UIButtons` have been pressed.

I have x number of `UIButtons` which I created programmatically.
Each button has its own unique tag (starting at 100 and incrementing upwards.)

When you click on a button is runs this:

```
- (void)myButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    [self handleButton:sender];
}

- (void)handleButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    // ???
}
```

If and only if the user has clicked on all buttons do a want an instance `[self allButtonsClicked]` to run.

What is the best way to do this? Should I make a `NSMutableArray`, and check to see if the tag number is in the `NSMutableArray` and if it is not, then add it.
And then when the `NSMutableArray` is equal in size to the x number of buttons then run `[self allButtonsClicked]`.

What is the simplest method to make sure each and every button has been clicked?

---

*edit I figured it out after typing it out. Writing it out helped me get it.

---

```
-(void)letterreveal: (id)sender {

    //data
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    //action
    [self clickcheck:[NSNumber numberWithInt:button.tag]];
}


-(void)clickcheck:(NSNumber*)currenttag {

    if ([self.buttonPressCounts containsObject:currenttag]) {
        NSLog(@"case A");
    }
    else {
        [self.buttonPressCounts addObject:currenttag];
         NSLog(@"case B");

        if([self.buttonPressCounts count]==[self.currentword length])
        {
            NSLog(@"fininshed");
        }
    }
}
```

buttonPressCounts is a NSMutablearray.
I just had to make sure to set it whenI made the buttons.

```
      self.buttonPressCounts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.currentword length]];
```

currentword is a NSString (each button is a letter derived from the NSString).

Answer (score 1):

You could create an `NSMutableSet` with all buttons and then remove each clicked button from that set until it is empty. Once the set is empty, you have certainly clicked all buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind, if a button was pressed once or more often, use a member ivar of NSMutableSet.

And I would use a number of the tag, but add /remove the button itself.